# What happens if I start an application with graphical interface before user logs on?

Tags: windows

If I run `gpedit.msc`, then go to `computer configuration` -> `windows settings` -> `scripts`, add a new startup script that opens an application that has graphical interface.

The script would get executed before a user logs on. Once a user logs on, he would be able to see the process in task manager, but he wouldn't be able to use this application(or am I wrong?). So my question is, where does this application ( or it's GUI ) go ?  What exactly happens in this scenario?

Comment: Process you started with user credentials that is logged off will start in session 0 (zero) and wouldn't be available for user when one logged in since this one would be in another session

Comment: "wouldn't be available" actually isn't correct words, when user will login, one can communicate with program in session 0 for example over message queues or user can simply kill it, but program itself won't be available on  desktop.

Comment: If the program is started the way I described, it is not started with any user credentials at all. That actually creates another question, which user does the process belong to?

Comment: confirmed. the process belongs to `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` user

Comment: If process belongs to `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` user, it's means there is something really wrong. Usually ownership for startup script assigned to administrators and regular users having simply read/execute permissions.